# How to rig up Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, unit-testing

just installed Silverlight Tools All with nuget.  I was hoping to find the Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing namespace as per some of the online documentation / blogs I've been reading?  Am I looking in the right place?

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SilverlightToolkit-All

... hoping to rig up either AgUnit (Ag as in the chemistry periodic table symbol for Silver) http://agunit.codeplex.com/releases/view/70609, or perhaps Resharper.

Humour: did a rainman, but I selected the "all" version.  So, I want all of it.  Why am I not getting all of it?  Maybe I should download it again.  Was that definitely the only "all" thing I could click on?  Grr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get hold of Jeff Wilcox (the author).  He said, 'it isn't packaged with the toolkit, it's separate. I believe some community folks packaged it up but i haven't released it on nuget unfortunately, sorry!'

No problem.  Well thanks Jeff for making it available in the first place.  What's an extra hoop to jump through to a developer anyway.  That'll teach me for making too many assumptions  ;-).

---

**previous update**

went to [silverlight.codeplex.com] http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets and downloaded the latest source code.  I discovered that Jeff Wilcox is still updating the testing .dll (last change back in Feb).

So I'm digging through the source code.  Took a while to find unit.testing.csproj under .\SLToolKit\Silverlight4\Infrastructure

Found that there's a dependency on Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Silverlight

I'm guessing that this .dll is part of any of the Visual Studios greater than professional.  Am I wrong?

Even though the sourcecode is kept in the SilverlightToolkit, the Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing.dll to my knowledge isn't shipped with any of the NuGet downloads.  I wonder why?  Getting closer at least.

---

Giving up on where the .dll comes from for now (still curious though), and am taking the versions from .\Silverlight4\Source\Binaries that came with the source code instead.

---

Awesome: Resharper picked it right up with those little circle things over on the left margin.

Did I just answer my own question?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace a_namespace
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Class1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }

    }
}
```